# C++ 'GET' request or how do you download files to work with in C++?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, curl, libcurl

Alright I've spent a good three days trying this, here's the scenario:

I want to download a '.csv' file from Google and then do stuff with the data from the file. It's for a Win32 Console Application. I have the latter down, I just cannot for the life of me figure out how to download the file. I've heard of libcurl, curlpp, ptypes, rolling my own, just using the .NET api, and been told a bunch of times:

> ...it's just a GET request

Well that's all well and good, but I must be missing something because it seems like everyone was just born knowing how to do this. I have been combing through books looking to figure this out and even had a huge problem with LNKerrors after traveling down the road with "The Art of C++" for a while.

All that being said, I have learned a LOT from this, but at this point I just want to know how to do it. The API for C++ is seriously lacking, no example code to be found. Tutorials online are almost non-existent. And no book out there seems to think this is important.

Can someone please throw me a life raft? I'm a man on the edge here.

**edit**

By "from Google" I mean that I want to download a .csv file that they host. An example can be [found here.](http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:AAPL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [bend this](http://www.luckyspin.org/?p=28) to your will.

Now that I have kinda answered your question. Why C++? Nothing against the language, but pick the best language for the job. Perl, PHP, and Python(and I am sure more) all have great documentation and support on this kind of operation.

In perl(the one I am familiar with) it's just about 3-5 lines of code.

---

Here is the code snippet [previously available in](http://www.luckyspin.org/?p=28) (from [WayBackMachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20060903181348/http://www.luckyspin.org/?p=28)):

```
/*
 * This is a very simple example of how to use libcurl from within 
 * a C++  program. The basic idea is that you want to retrieve the 
 * contents of a web page as a string. Obviously, you can replace 
 * the buffer object with anything you want and adjust elsewhere 
 * accordingly.
 * 
 * Hope you find it useful..
 * 
 * Todd Papaioannou
 */

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "curl/curl.h"

using namespace std;

// Write any errors in here
static char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

// Write all expected data in here
static string buffer;

// This is the writer call back function used by curl
static int writer(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                  std::string *buffer)
{
  // What we will return
  int result = 0;

  // Is there anything in the buffer?
  if (buffer != NULL)
  {
    // Append the data to the buffer
    buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);

    // How much did we write?
    result = size * nmemb;
  }

  return result;
}

// You know what this does..
void usage()
{
  cout < < "curltest: \n" << endl;
  cout << "  Usage:  curltest url\n" << endl;
} 

/*
 * The old favorite
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc > 1) 
  {
    string url(argv[1]);

    cout < < "Retrieving " << url << endl;

    // Our curl objects
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode result;

    // Create our curl handle
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
      // Now set up all of the curl options
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, argv[1]);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

      // Attempt to retrieve the remote page
      result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

      // Always cleanup
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

      // Did we succeed?
      if (result == CURLE_OK)
      {
        cout << buffer << "\n";
        exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "Error: [" << result << "] - " << errorBuffer;
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I presume the answer is in the "then do stuff with the data from the file".  Seems silly to involve another process, especially if this needs to be fast.

Comment: Jesse -- it doesnt seem that silly to spend an extra five minutes downloading the file with say a libcurl command line rather than spending three plus days not getting a file at all!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just using what's already there?

[UrlDownloadToFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: I've tried this and had a number of problems and never actually downloaded the file. Also of note to anyone looking upon this later, if you're getting "LPSCTWR" conversion errors, use URLDownloadToFileA() instead, because C++ doesn't like you not having wide strings.

Comment: Hmm - I've never had problems using URLDownloadToFile(). Usually, I do simply:

URLDownloadToFileA(NULL, "url", "file", 0, NULL);

and that works. If IE can download it (without a dialog prompt), then UrlDownloadToFile() should work. If IE prompts for something with a dialog, you have to implement

Comment: an authentication callback which implements IBindStatusCallback, IAuthenticate and IHttpSecurity and then pass that callback as the last parameter to UrlDownloadToFile().

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on the Win32 platform, there is one built in libary you can use to implement a GET request in a *relatively* straightforward way: WinInet, which is part of the Win32 SDK.  The [basic reference for WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483.aspx) can be found on MSDN.

Be warned there will be some rough sledding ahead if you're not familiar with the Win32 API.  There is a fairly useful block of example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384322(VS.85).aspx)

You will get linker errors if you fail to add the appropriate library reference to your project.  It sounds like you've learned some lessons there already so I'll keep it breif, but be assured that you will find references to both the libraries and header file references you will need in the Win32 documentation (you just have to learn where on the page to look for it).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the standard library. Since it's win32, you can follow Paul Keister's advice.

But have a look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), and since you are in C++, I'd recommend [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) it's very usefull too. They are very handy tools!

Comment: I can't figure out how to get libcurl installed. I'll give POCO a look though.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382925(VS.85).aspx), which also comes with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

*> no example code to be found*

???

Dozens of samples have been posted for 15 years..
See on api ng news://comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
(samples in C)

(COM, INET, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I too have been looking for a good http lib for C++ but haven't found the 'perfect' lib.  [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is fantastic but quite low level for a simple http library (though the [http client examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) are a good start).  The [C++ Networking Library*](http://cpp-netlib.wiki.sourceforge.net/) (cpp-netlib) looks like it's on track, building a higher-level api on top of asio, but is not very mature.  Check out the [http_client example](http://cpp-netlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cpp-netlib/trunk/libs/network/example/http_client.cpp?view=markup).

I'm either going to write my own wrappers around asio or extend (and contribute) to cpp-netlib unless I can find a better option.

(BTW libcurl is *not* a better option for me.  It's a much larger api than I want and very unwieldy for something like an http client, especially in C++.  Don't get me wrong, it's a great library but not appropriate for a simple http client.)

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't really have an API per se.  To do a GET request, your program needs to open a TCP socket connection to the site in question, and send the information down the socket to conform with the HTTP specification, see [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).  There are likely a number of libraries you could find to help with this, for example, you could look at what the open source program wget uses.  If you're coding it yourself, it'd be helpful to use a packet sniffing tool.  You could see exactly what your browser sends to the web server to get the file back, and just send exactly that message.  It's not too hard, but it is pretty hard.  TCP is a pretty big learning curve initially.

By the way, what do you mean by "from google?"